# Understanding use case of instance variable and local variable

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

Suppose I have a user class as below

```
class User
  def initialize
    test
  end

  def test
    name = ['name1','name2', 'name3']
    returned_value = test1(name)
    lots of if else condition based on returned_value 
  end

  def test1(name)
    test2(name)
  end

  def test2(name)
    test3(name)
  end

  def test3(name)

  end
end
```

And this user class has some methods like test, test1.. and each method do some calculation one single array and then return the array. Now based on the returned value test method add or delete elements from the array. This become very ugly with lot of if else condition because returned value could be blank, one element, two dimensional array and so one.

But if I use an instance variable then I don't have to return any value and so I don't need any if else statement based on the returned value and my code looks clean. For example

```
class User
  def initialize
    @name = ['name1','name2', 'name3']
    test
  end

  def test

    test1
  end

  def test1
    test2
  end

  def test2
    test3
  end

  def test3

  end
end
```

My question is, should I use instance variable or not in this case? An explanation would be nice.

**Update:**
In short it would be, I want to manipulate one single array in different methods of a Class. Now, I can create the array inside test method and then pass it to other methods (first case in my above example) or I can create the array in initialize method and then I don't have to pass the array every time(second case in my example above). So my questions is

Is my first/second approach is bad/okay? Or both approach is okay to use?

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have data that needs to be accessible to many methods in a class, then instance variables is a good way to manage that.

I generally use instance variables in PORO classes for two reasons

1. To store information, usually at initialization, that many of the
   class methods need access to. This is what you're asking about
   above.
2. To memoize resource intensive methods.

For example to avoid doing an api call every time I access customer_data I would replace

```
def customer_data
  HTTParty.get... (some api call)
end
```

with

```
def customer_data
  @customer_data ||= HTTParty.get... (some api call)
end
```

`@customer_data` is only used within that method, but if I call the method multiple times only one api call is needed.  This assumes (of course) that for a given class object there is only one associated customer.